# Error CS1569 although I have permissions to create file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an assembly that when compiled throws the following error:

> Error CSC CS1569: Error while generating the xml-dumentation 
>   'MyAssembly.XML'
>   ('Access denied ')

As from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1569) this error occurs when we don´t have write-permissions for a given file (as suggested within the error). However I start VS as admin, so I assume to have write-permissions (checked within the permission-settings within widows). What´s more crazy is that after compiling the file exists, however there´s no DLL with name `MyAssembly`.

EDIT: I noticed, that when the file is created by VS I don´t even have **permission to read the file-settings** in Windows when using Explorer.

Obviously VS creates files it can´t read nor modify.

Comment: are you trying to compile through some msbuild script? if yes, then you may want to make sure that you are not debugging in VS

Comment: Not that I knew. I debug directly in VS.